# Start GDM (gnome display manager) session via SSH without root

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, gnome

Is there a way to remotely start a GNOME session without root via SSH?

### Background

I am trying to access the CD drive (`/dev/cdrom -> /dev/sr0`) of a remote machine via SSH.

Remote machine is running Ubuntu 18.

The problem is that permission to write to the drive file (`/dev/sr0`) is set in a file ACL to the **gdm user** when no one is logged into the computer (can be verified with `getfacl /dev/sr0`).

When a user logs into the computer via GNOME (i.e., in person), then the ACL gets updated to match their user.

Comment: I don't think you're _supposed_ to be able to do that. The idea is probably that only the _locally_ logged user can access the CD drive. But anyways, has the user you log in via ssh any extra permissions (what does `id` say?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a SSH connection with X11 forwarding enabled (and have a local X11 server running), you should be able to start a GNOME session on the remote server by using the command `gnome-session`.

But you'll find that won't give you access to the CD drive.

You see, the CD drive permissions are granted to *a locally logged-in user* only, even if the login is done in text mode on a virtual console. Not to simply whoever is having a GNOME session. The system will know the difference. The ACL assignment is done by `udev`: the `uaccess` tag assigned to devices in `/lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules` will determine which devices will get this treatment.

If you want to have the capability to use the CD drive while logged on remotely over SSH, your user account needs to have the `cdrom` group membership assigned to it. That needs to be done only once, but it requires root access. For example, if your user account is named `helper`:

```
sudo usermod -a -G cdrom helper
```

or

```
sudo gpasswd --add helper cdrom
```

or

```
sudo adduser helper cdrom
```

After any one of those commands is executed, you'll need to log out to make the change effective. On your next login, you'll be a member of the `cdrom` group (in addition to whatever group(s) you were member of before) and can always use the CD drive, whether you're logged in locally or remotely. *That's what the `cdrom` group is for.*

Other groups with similar purposes are listed here: https://wiki.debian.org/SystemGroups

Comment: I assume that the "without root" from the OP's Q means no sudo either. Otherwise they could just mount the cd and be done with the whole thing.

Comment: Yes, in order to be able to use the CD drive remotely, someone with root privileges needs to grant permission.

Answer (score 0):

I do this with the MATE desktop by starting Xnest at :1 and a smaller-than-full-screen resolution.  I  then do an `export DISPLAY=:1` and then `ssh -Y user@remotehost mate-session` and I get my full desktop in the smaller Xnest X "server" window.  (Xnest at this point is acting as both a X server and X client)